# ActiveAdmin navigation_menu doesn't seem to be changing the menu at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to use ActiveAdmin to try and have a Category having many Items. As such my Item is registered with AA and says that it `belongs_to :category` as well as to change menu with `navigation_menu :category`. I have made no other changes at all. Now, I don't see any changes happening to the menu, when I visit categories/1. I expect it to show me an entry to make an item.

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I am using AA 1.0.0.pre1, also tried using the GH master. Same results.

Comment: I concur. With the belongs_to on items, the navigation_menu seems to serve no purpose. I tried several variations with no noticeable difference in behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue that has not been resolved as of 8/28/2015. Currently, `navigation_menu` is forced to the parent object when a `belongs_to` relationship is defined on the resource.

```
  if config.belongs_to? and config.menu_item_options[:parent].blank?
    navigation_menu :default
    menu false
  end
```

CITE: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2637